# Custom swatch for a legend in core plot

Tags: ios

How can i give custom color to a legend in bar graph . I have three legends. Each legend title is populated using legendTitleForBarPlot .But how can i give custom color to a swatch in the legend

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
yourLegend.fill  = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: I am filling bars using-(CPTFill*)barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot*)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if(colorArray && [colorArray count] > index)
    {
        CGColorRef color    = ((UIColor *)[colorArray objectAtIndex:index]).CGColor;
        return [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:color]];
    }
    return nil;
}

Comment: edo, that is a standard fill. Custom is "whatever you want", like images

Answer (score 0):

According to the [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreplot-discuss/z_IRIbcSwlA), you basically tell the delegate "should draw swatch at..." to not do anything (return false), then you access the Core Animation code via the context and manually draw your own symbols.

In other words, manual Quartz2d